# VB.net Get all string between to 2 word condition

Tags: vb.net

Here's the scenario, I use webbrowser after it loads, the source code can be view in richbox, and there is another button which when click I want to get all the string between the 2 word filter. See example below.

Condition: `<td>Some Text Here!</td>`
Input - html sourcecode in 1st richbox:

```
<body>
    <td><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.w4schools.com">Visit W4Schools.com!</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.w5schools.com">Visit W5Schools.com!</a></td>
    <a href="http://www.not-included.com">Visit NotIncluded.com!</a>  
</body>
```

Output - output to be generate into 2nd richbox:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<a href="http://www.w4schools.com">Visit W4Schools.com!</a>
<a href="http://www.w5schools.com">Visit W5Schools.com!</a>
```

Comment: thank u in advance for ur answer.. It will help me a lot

Comment: where did you get that HTML? `<img>` don't have a close tag and the syntax is wrong. [Reference Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: I suggest you check the [Regex Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Regex.Matches Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx). Once you try something and have a problem with it, come back so you can get help. Good luck :)

Comment: sorry2x for the img.. but its just examle..well I edit it..